# How can I check if there is an integer after a character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I call the `input` function and I want to check whether there is a character and if there is an integer after that character. If there is, print something different. What would I call the integer after the character in python?

Example:

```
i = input()
for line in enumerate(i):
    for x,c in enumerate(line):
        if c == '>':
            print('Yes')
        if c == '>'+int: #Int is referring to the integer after the symbol
            print('No')
```

Comment: what is `input` exactly? the `input` function works in terms of a single string so it has no concept of lines

Comment: It'is not clear, what `input` could be, and what the desired output is. Please be more specific.

Comment: Since you are using `enumerate`, `x` holds the index value, so you can check `if line[x+1].isdigit()`

Comment: Sorry I misspelled input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `input`.
`line` is a tuple of an integer and a character, so using `for` with this tuple is not very usefull.

If you want to test, if the `line` contains `>` and that after that character only digits follow, you can use this:

```
line = input()
head, sep, tail = line.rpartition('>')
if sep:
    if not tail:
        print("yes")
    elif tail.isdigit():
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop is only ever going to iterate over a single character, so it'll never find any matches. You essentially are just looking if any part of the string from the second character onwards is a number so just use a slice and any.

```
if any(x.isdigit() for x in i[1:]):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```